# DB design Linking Orders to PO

Tags: database-design

I,m building a Ecommerce site, i,m stuck at one database design issue.

say suppose end users place below orders.

```
+---------+--------+------+--------+
|         | Tomato | Rice | Maggie |
+---------+--------+------+--------+
| Order 1 | 1 KG   |      |        |
| Order 2 | 2 KG   | 5 KG | 100 Gm |
| Order 3 | 2 KG   | 1 KG |        |
+---------+--------+------+--------+
```

I have to consolidate above orders and make PO which, something like below.

```
PoID    Product Quantity    WSName  Cost    Status      OrderDate   
1       Tomato  5KG         Shop1   100     Confirmed   13/9/2014   
2       Rice    6KG         Stock   600     Confirmed   13/9/2014   
3       Maggi   100GM       Shop1   40      Waiting     13/9/2014
```

but using above design I cant track Order related to PO, can you please suggest a better design.

Regards
Manish

Answer (score 0):

You need to recognize that orders (from customers) and purchase orders (to vendors) all have one or more items.  Your order table is shown in an un-normalized state.  It should be normalized into an order header and order items.

Similarly, obtaining the stock to fill customer orders by making POs to vendors should also be structured as a header and item, assuming that your vendors accept orders for more than one item at a time.

Furthermore, your purchaser probably purchases in bulk and fills many order details at once to enjoy bulk discounts or savings on shipping, for example.  If this is the case, then you might want to replace a direct relationship from `ORDER_ITEM` to `PO_ITEM` with an intersection entity, such as `PO_ITEM_DETAIL`.

Consider the following ERD:

[image]

As an aside, I would consider it an unusual requirement to link customer orders to purchase orders in such a direct fashion.  This would make sense if your business is based on a "drop shipment" model.  If, on the other hand, you fill orders from your own inventory, then a linkage between customer orders and purchase orders isn't necessarily applicable most of the time.

Comment: I have to think about it, thanks for your suggestion though.. Actually I,m a startup and buying a space for warehouse and buying stock which I really dont know if customers will dose not fit in my budget for now.. I have get the orders from whole Saler and deliver it to the end user, atleast for now, in future I might consider building a warehouse.